# Normal modes of two wires fastened together

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, waves

The problem is to find the normal frequencies of the system formed by two fastened wires of length L, and different mass per unit length.

I already wrote the boundary conditions, but I need to know if the joint has to be a node.

I'm pretty sure it has to, otherwise it wouldn't be in a normal mode, but I can't set it up straight in a rigorous way.

The boundary conditions I imposed are:

$y_1(0,t)=y_2(2L,t)=0$

$y_1(L,t)=y_2(L,t)$

$\frac{\partial y_1}{\partial x}(L,t)=\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial x}(L,t)$

Where $y_1(x,t)=A_1e^{i(k_1 x-\omega t)}+B_1e^{i(-k_1 x-\omega t)}$ and $y_2$ is written similarly.

Thanks!

Comment: Think of the extremes: a thread and a chain put together. If you shake the chain, what will happen to the thread? Will there be a joint? Obviously, the chain will move the thread as it was a free end. What will happen if you shake the thread instead?